# Bone heat weighting failed to find solution for one or more bones (tried all fix, don't work)

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I've modeled with guy this week and I wanted to rig it, but I got this error. I've tried all the fixes I've founded (remove doubles, deleted constraints, delete modifier, add and apply decimate modifier, etc.).

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: No blend file provided

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2613

Comment: @Tak It is preferably to advise a new user *how* to upload blend files if a blend is required.

Comment: @RayMairlot sorry, I updated the question myself, but will do this next time, no worries :)

Comment: @MagicalPaladin the .blend file doesn't have any armatures just mesh

Comment: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2615 sorry

Comment: @MagicalPaladin you can update your question by placing the link under the "Share this file:" in the above link, can you try doing this? :)

Comment: it's done, link changed

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-error-messag

Comment: already done that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I separated all objects and parented each one by one and it seems that the belt and torso are the issue. I tried to recalculate the normals and Remove doubles, but it seems that there is something wrong with the two. Maybe try Retopo-ing the the two. Also for whatever reason there is no weight appearing in the weight paint mode which brings me to the conclusion that you will have to manually weight paint the model after fixing the two objects of course.

Additionally I looked up the issue and found a concise list of the stuff you need to check in your model on a reddit forum Here it is:

> - Anything that has lots of intersecting meshes seems to bork the auto weightpainting. If you separate loose parts, weight all the parts, and
>   then join them, you can get an approximate weight painting. Other
>   things worth checking
> - Are the rig and mesh aligned on the axis properly?
> - Have you applied scale and rotation on everything you're weighting?
> - Did you make sure to keep the x - axis mirror option on when rigging? The weight painting gets wonky when things are less
>   symmetrical.
> - Have you removed double vertices, checked your mesh for bits that don't aren't connected, and recalculated normals?
> - Is your mesh or armature too large? Sometimes scaling it down can help. That error message is frustrating because it gives very few
>   clues as to what you're doing wrong.

Here is the file:

[image]

Comment: Your Welcome Bro

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why (I think it's just Blender's Automatic Weighting Algorithm), but it worked when I added a subsurface modifier then did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then *With Automatic Wieghts*. After that, I removed the Subsurface modifier and it was all fine.

Hope this helps

Comment: Will try it and tell if it's works

Comment: Just tried it, not working, could you please share your file and tell me which blender version you use ?

Comment: I use Blender 2.78a and here I've tried it multiple times with the file you provided. Make sure you don't Apply the modifier.

Comment: Never mind, when I do that Blender doesn't give the error message, but doesn't add the wights.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the Mesh Deform method to rig your character:

First create a lowpoly model of the character and make sure the lowpoly is around the highpoly.

Then go to the original mesh and add a `Mesh Deform` modifier. Set the lowpoly mesh as the object in the `object` box and then parent the lowpoly to the armature.

NOTE: Make sure that you DO NOT parent the original mesh to the armature. Also make sure the low poly model has a black shader attached to `volume` instead of `surface`.

Blend File:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6P9xP7owZILY2ZKUk1pQTNfQUk?usp=sharing

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Update: Extended the "NOTE".

Comment: Tell me if it works

Comment: Added blend file

Comment: works i just need to correct weight

Comment: Please vote or accept as answer if it worked