# Bone Heat Weigthing failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, error

I am trying to do automatic weighting on this object, but I am getting a "Automatic Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones".

I have tried alot of different thing

Removing doubles
Removing all modifiers
Subsurface
Decimate
Removing Non Mainfold Vertices

Here is my .blend file: [image]

Comment: Hi, welcome: it would be better if you could use this other service (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) because it helps this QA site to keep a durable link to .blend files, for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this:

- I first removed doubles. This is caused because of non-manifold
  geometry in your model as shown in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69907/2517).
- I then switched into Edit Mode
- Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> to find non manifold geometry in the model
- I then unchecked all the list except the Boundaries as shown below:

[image]

- I then hit <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and type `Dissolve Vertices` as shown below:

[image]

- After that I did automatic weighting and it worked perfect as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Updated .blend file can be found here: [image]

Comment: Hmm, I get this error though when i try to dissolve them: Invalid Boundry to join faces. Also, it doesn't say Mesh: Dissolve Vertices. It's just Dissolve Vertices if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Olaf not sure what you did for this to happen? If you followed the exact steps mentioned in my answer it should work without any problems, I've added the updated file as well. If you still can't make it work then send me a link of your current file which is not the same as the one you uploaded in your question, right?

Comment: I deleted the doubles, selected only boundries and typed in dissolve vertices. Problem i have with the updated file is that the materials are gone and i have no clue how to get them back :). And here is the latest version https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwvla0eaisn74dq/daemon.blend?dl=0

Comment: @Olaf I followed the steps I told you on the file and it worked. I updated my answer and included the updated file which has the materials as well.

Comment: Probably me and my rookie knowledge then, thanks though!