# Help! Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging, error

im trying to rig the character of Lol Ahri in **Blender 2.9**, i want her to walk and wave. I downloaded the object(ahri), and used the basic human armature.
[image: i downloaded the object(ahri), and used the basic human armature]

But when i try to parent the model with the rig, it shows me the error "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones". I tried to use automatic weigths
[image: i choose automatic weigths]
[image: the error]

So i started looking for solutions, **this is what i tried**:
MERGE BY DISTANCE (or remove doubles), scaled up, decimate geometry, delete loose, remove all modifiers, any of the bones are showing off, just using a single bone, changed the merge distance to 0.002, and placed the root bone at the center of the model.
[image: here i removed doubles]
[image]

the link to the project is: https://pasteall.org/blend/af6843868fb648748cb9687925586701

if you could help me i would be very grateful :)

Comment: weird because merge by distance make it work, even though it won't be properly parented and you need to bring some corrections afterwards

Comment: You only used that option and worked? Maybe i have to reinstall the program? And if you could please tell me what corrections i have to make

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-error-message  Removing non manifold geometry from mesh (select non manifold verts & delete  to test) removes the warning also.   Also recommend making the rig scale unity (1, 1, 1)  by applying scale.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it

Comment: It worked!! Thanks :)))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  **batFINGER**! Im going to post the solution in photos, maybe helps someone who was a little lost like me :))

Select only the object and choose *edit mode*, there click in **select**, and then select **all by trait**. There select **non manifold**. [image]

In the box that apears in the bottom, deselect **Vertices**[image]

Still in edit mode go to **mesh**, select **merge** and click in **By Distance**
[image]

Now try **parenting** in *object mode*
[image]

And for me it worked :)
[image]