# Bone Heat Weighting: armature deform with weighting

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, bones, parent

[image]heres a link https: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7f9c6ikxme5xgjy/untitled.blend?dl=0

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkiWBSSuxLw&t=944s but when I got to set the parent for the rig it wouldn't work. I tried to remove some unnecessary verts but it affects the mesh... what do I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bone heat weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones error message](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones-error-message)   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209973/help-bone-heat-weighting-failed-to-find-solution-for-one-or-more-bones

Answer (score 0):

You have overlapping vertices, go in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> > <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.